# File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks

Tags: windows-10

Whenever I reboot my laptop, for my laptop to be seen on the network, I have to open the properties of my network adapter and  turn "File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks" off, save, then open and turn "File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks" on. At that point my computer and shares can be seen on the network. 
I have tried with my Lan adapter and my Wifi Adapter.Each has to go thru the above steps.

OS = Windows 10 Version 1809.

I have checked that SMB is turned on in Windows features.
I have checked "Turn on Network Discovery". Everyone on the network should be able to see the computer. The entire network consists of one other Windows 10 computer. :)

My laptop has a shared printer attached and some shared drives. They cannot be seen by my desktop until I do the Off and On thing above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What problem are you solving by turning sharing off then on? Is anything that's possibly related to this being logged in the Windows Event logs? Please [edit] your question with this information.

Comment: Sorry. Until I go thru the process of turning off and on the "File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks"  my laptop cannot be seen on the network.

Comment: Nothing I can see in the Event Viewer is related.

Comment: Did you already check and *Turn on Network Discovery in Network and Sharing Center*, and see if that helps resolve where the workaround is no longer needed? You might consider an [edit] explaining what all you have tried, and also be clear in terms of what is not seeing it on the network. Is it an attached printer that's shared, some AP connection, from a Linux machine on Wi-Fi only, etc. for example?